# Android Studio Emulator with both the Google Play Store and Root?

Tags: rooting, android-emulator, google-play-services

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#system-image says

> To ensure app security and a consistent experience with physical devices, system images with the Google Play Store included are signed with a release key, which means that you cannot get elevated privileges (root) with these images. If you require elevated privileges (root) to aid with your app troubleshooting, you can use the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) system images that do not include Google apps or services.

But what if I wanted both root AND Google services? how could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: magisk's author topjohnwu says it's doable: https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1070241061010857984 and there is also this file in the magisk's repo: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/scripts/emulator.sh
also see
https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/732#issuecomment-446542064

Comment: Both solutions work with Play Store system images: [MagiskOnEmulator](https://github.com/shakalaca/MagiskOnEmulator), [Official Magisk AVD scripts](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/tree/master/scripts)

Answer (score 2):

First go here:

https://opengapps.org

I selected this option:

| Platform | Android | Variant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x86 | 6 | pico |

but newer Android should work as well. Then open Android Studio. On "Select
Hardware" screen, select a device without "Play Store" icon.

### With Google APIs

On "System Image" screen, I selected this option:

| API Level | ABI | Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | x86 | Android 7 Google APIs |

but newer APIs should work as well. You should only need one file from the Zip
archive:

```
Core\vending-x86.tar.lz
```

Inside this will be another file:

```
vending-x86\nodpi\priv-app\Phonesky\Phonesky.apk
```

Now, start the device:

```
emulator -list-avds
emulator -avd Pixel_3a_XL_API_24 -writable-system
```

Next, install Google Play Store. Note that you cannot use the normal method of
drag APK to device screen, or you will get one of these errors:

```
The APK failed to install.<br/> Error: Could not parse error string

The APK failed to install.<br/> Error: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE:
Package com.android.vending signatures do not match the previously installed
version; ignoring!

The APK failed to install.<br/> Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES:
Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1047870024.tmp/base.apk:
META-INF/BNDLTOOL.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl1047870024.tmp/base.apk is signed
using APK Signature Scheme v2, but no such signature was found. Signature
stripped?
```

Install like this:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb push Phonesky.apk /system/priv-app
adb reboot
```

After reboot, you should then be able to start Google Play Store as normal.

### Without Google APIs

Using the method above with Google APIs image, you still get some apps such as
YouTube. If you want to install different version of one of these apps, use
this method. On "System Image" screen, I selected this option:

| API Level | ABI | Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | x86 | Android 7 |

but newer APIs should work as well. You need these files from the Zip archive:

```
Core\gmscore-x86.tar.lz
Core\vending-x86.tar.lz
```

Then extract these from the above files:

```
gmscore-x86\nodpi\priv-app\PrebuiltGmsCore\PrebuiltGmsCore.apk
vending-x86\nodpi\priv-app\Phonesky\Phonesky.apk
```

Use the same method above to install the APKs. After reboot, you should then be
able to install YouTube or whatever app. Note that unlike above, you dont
actually need to run the Google Play setup or even start the Google Play app at
the end.

### External links

https://github.com/89z/googleplay/blob/f98b78a7/docs/play-store.md

Comment: Does doing this make the emulator rooted? Or in other words, apps that need root access can run on the emulator?

Comment: `adb root` provides root access only to the `shell` for commandline use, not to the apps. Testing root apps requires rooting the emulator anyways - be it the Play Store image or not.

Comment: @Zombo please calm down. And reread Andrew's [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218850/android-studio-emulator-with-both-the-google-play-store-and-root/245551?noredirect=1#comment328102_245551). I don't *"disagree"* with your answer. It's just a partial solution to the rooting problem. For many users root is required to test apps, not just to issue commands. Your use case seems to be very limited.

Comment: I appreciate everyone including your contribution, but at this point, looks like we don't know what the asker's real use case is without clarifying (and I'm afraid they don't seem to visit this site anymore). It just seems that [the other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218851/44325), Irfan, and I were thinking about having *a rooted emulator* (i.e. access to `su`) for testing apps/commands that require root access from the emulator/device directly...

Comment: please revise your answer and outline if/how *google play services* is included that way (only read about *vending* but *gms* not mentioned anywhere)

Comment: Did not work for me : on Android 11.0 google api image - Emulator gets stuck on boot after installing Phonesky.apk

Answer (score 0):

I think thing the best course of action would be to download and install a third-party Android Emulator. If you are on Windows, I would recommend  [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/). As it can be easily rooted with this tutorial  [here](https://sangams.com.np/how-to-root-bluestacks-latest-version/). If you need any help, feel free to reply to this message.

Hope this helps you out!

Red Prez

Comment: what do you recommend for linux?